# Iterate through folder array ( file system like ) and return HTML nested list

Tags: php, html, arrays, recursion

I am having the following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Homework2 (1).java
    [test2] => Array
    (
    )
    [1] => space-art-hd-473771.jpg
    [2] => Homework2.java
    [3] => factura_oct_2013.pdf
    [test] => Array
    (
        [0] => Homework2 (1).java
        [1] => space-art-hd-473771.jpg
        [2] => Homework2.java
    )
    [test3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Homework2 (1).java
        [testintest] => Array
        (
            [0] => Homework2 (1).java
            [1] => space-art-hd-473771.jpg
            [2] => Homework2.java
        )
        [1] => space-art-hd-473771.jpg
        [2] => Homework2.java
    )
)
```

and I am trying to display an HTML nested list. So each child of the array should be a new UL in the parent UL. I have tried to get this recursive but I only managed to get a lot of values that I already have.

```
function map2ul($file_map,$html="") {
    var_dump($file_map);
    print "<br>";
    if ($html == "") $html = '<ul>';
    else $html .= '<ul>';
    foreach ($file_map as $df) :
        if (is_array($df)) :
            $html .= $this->map2ul($df,$html);
        else :
            $html .= '<li>';
            $html .= $df;
            $html .= '</li>';
        endif;
    endforeach;
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

This is what I have tried but it seems that the foreach statement is recurred more times than it's needed.

Can someone please point me the error so I can understand better how to recurse this?

Comment: I know that on codeigniter I can use the UL/OL function from the HTML helper to render that array but I would like to understand better what happens over there. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in this lines:

```
if ($html == "") $html = '<ul>';
else $html .= '<ul>';
```

When you try to call this function recursively, the non-empty `$html` is passed recursively causing the interior loop to glue sub-folder contents. @AgreeOrNot has already pointed one solution. The other is not to pass `$html` to the recursively called function:

```
$html .= $this->map2ul($df);
```

---

But I think that your approach introduces some unnecessary logic and processing.

By analyzing the array we can draw one important conclusion: if the array value is an array, the corresponding key is folder name. In other case the value is file name:

```
function map2ul($file_map) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($file_map as $file_id_or_folder_name => $file_name_or_folder_content) {
        // if the element is a file
        if ( ! is_array($file_name_or_folder_content)) {
            $html .= '<li>' . $file_name_or_folder_content . '</li>';
        } else { // if the element is a folder
            $html .= '<li>/ ' . $file_id_or_folder_name . '</li>';
        }
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

Now it's enough to inject sub-folders contents where it's necessary, i.e. for folders:

```
function map2ul($file_map) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($file_map as $file_id_or_folder_name => $file_name_or_folder_content) {
        // if the element is a file
        if ( ! is_array($file_name_or_folder_content)) {
            $html .= '<li>' . $file_name_or_folder_content . '</li>';
        } else { // if the element is a folder
            $html .= '<li>/ ' . $file_id_or_folder_name . '</li>';
            // injecting sub-folder's contents
            $html .= map2ul($file_name_or_folder_content);
        }
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

---

### Edit

> if I want for this piece of code `$html .= '<li>' . $file_name_or_folder_content . '</li>';` to append the data-filepath attribute, which will be the parent_folder/file_name path, what do I need to do?

You have to pass the full path to the function. And the full path needs to be constructed at the function call:

```
function map2ul($file_map, $path = '') {
    $path = $path . '/';
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach ($file_map as $file_id_or_folder_name => $file_name_or_folder_content) {
        // if the element is a file
        if ( ! is_array($file_name_or_folder_content)) {
            $html .= '<li data-filepath="' . $path . $file_name_or_folder_content . '">' . $file_name_or_folder_content . '</li>';
        } else { // if the element is a folder
            $html .= '<li>/ ' . $file_id_or_folder_name . '</li>';
            $html .= map2ul($file_name_or_folder_content, $path . $file_id_or_folder_name);
        }
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';
    return $html;
}
```

Try without second parameter, e.g `map2ul($file_map)` and with second parameter, e.g `map2ul($file_map, 'c:/my_files')`.

Comment: you are right. I was rechecking the array structure and found out that you are totally right. I didn't got that perspective in my mind at 5:24 am;

Comment: if I want for this piece of code ` $html .= '<li>' . $file_name_or_folder_content . '</li>';` to append the `data-filepath` attribute, which will be the `parent_folder/file_name` path, what do I need to do? if I pass ` $html .= map2ul($file_name_or_folder_content,$file_id_or_folder_name);` it will only get the last parent appended. Which way is best to concatenate that `$file_id_or_folder_name` to get the full path?

Comment: Thanks. I've checked it up. I got into another approach to get that folders path. I just added the folder name to each UL and iterated with jQuery trough the <li> parents and built the folder path for each file.

Answer (score 2):

```
$html .= $this->map2ul($df,$html);
```

It shouldn't be a concatenation, because the recursive call is based on the parameter `$html` - that is, the concatenation is already done in the recursive call. Change it to:

```
$html = $this->map2ul($df,$html);
```